# Merge 2 queries to calculate 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Wondering how others would accomplish this or a best practice.  I would like to sum the SalesTotal and Transaction columns between the two select statements below while keaping the values from the first select statement for everything else; including those columns that were not included in the second select statement to their original values.

I would like to avoid using a cursor or much conditional logic.  Ideally if it can be done in a single SQL statement it would be preferred or maybe not?

```
SELECT Merchant, Department, SUM(SalesTotal) As 'SalesTotal', SUM(Transactions) As 'Transactions', FeeRate, SUM(Gross) As 'Gross', ((SUM(ItemA) * (1 - Rate)) * RateTwo) As 'Rate'
FROM Receipts a
    Where TransStatus = 1
Group By Merchant, Department, FeeRate, Rate, RateTwo
```

AND

```
SELECT Merchant, Department, SUM(SalesTotal) As 'SalesTotal', SUM(Transactions) As 'Transactions'
FROM Receipts a
Where TransStatus = 2
Group By Merchant, Department
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT (CASE WHEN TransStatus = 1 THEN Merchant ELSE 0 END) as 'Merchant' ,
   (CASE WHEN TransStatus = 1 THEN Department ELSE 0 END) as 'Department',
   (CASE  WHEN TransStatus = 1 THEN FeeRate ELSE 0 END) as 'FeeRate' , 
   SUM(CASE WHEN TransStatus = 1 THEN Gross ELSE 0 END) As 'Gross', 
   ((SUM(CASE WHEN TransStatus = 1 THEN ItemA ELSE 0 END) * (1 - Rate)) * RateTwo) As 'Rate'
   SUM(SalesTotal) As 'SalesTotal',
   SUM(Transactions) As 'Transactions'   
FROM Receipts
Group By Merchant, Department,
       CASE WHEN TransStatus = 1 THEN  FeeRate END,
       CASE WHEN TransStatus = 1 THEN  Rate END,
       CASE WHEN TransStatus = 1 THEN  RateTwo END
```

Comment: little explanation for illiterate like me? :)

Comment: A big truckload of conditional logic.WHen TransStatus=1 use the respective column.